# When using JPA2 EntityListener, how does it work if i use the in clause to update multiple rows?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

query : update Order set f='1' where key in (1,2,3,4,5)

```
@PostUpdate
public void postUpdate(Order order) {
    ....     
}
```

I wonder what happens if I work as above.

Comment: Can you add more info about code ? and also execute the code and if confusion or clarifcation then you can ask question here.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute a bulk update/jpql update query of the from "update Order set f='1' where key in (1,2,3,4,5)" you get those rows affected and nothing else. JPQL bulk updates/deletes run in the database, so they do not affect your java entities and do not cause entity lifecycle events to occur.